# Jekyll DataTables below sidebar

Tags: html, sass, datatables, jekyll, sidebar

I use minima theme for my Jekyll blog, and I created a custom sidebar through the file `sidebar.html` under the folder `_includes`.

```
<!-- Side navigation -->
<sidebar>
    {% for item in site.data.nav.toc %}
        <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for entry in item.subfolderitems %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.page }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</sidebar>
```

The TOC is under `_data` in a file called `nav.yml`.

```
toc:
- title: Research
  subfolderitems:
    - page: Crime Categories
      url: /posts/crime-categories/
```

I include this sidebar in `default.html` in the folder `_layouts`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ page.lang | default: site.lang | default: "en" }}">


  {%- include head.html -%}

  <body>
    {%- include header.html -%}

  

    <main class="page-content" aria-label="Content">

      {% include sidebar.html %}
      
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </main>

    {%- include footer.html -%}
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Then in the `minima` folder under the `_sass` folder, I add the sidebar into the `_base.scss` file.

```
/**
 * `main` element
 */
main {
  display: block; /* Default value of `display` of `main` element is 'inline' in IE 11. */
}

/**
 * sidebar element
 */
sidebar {
  float:left;
}
```

Currently, the DataTable element is in a blog post in the folder `_posts`.

```
---
layout: post
title: Sample page
date: 2022-8-25 9:00:01 --0000
permalink: /posts/sample-page/
datatable: true
---

Food    | Quantity sold | Time sold         | Cashier
------- | ------------- | ----------------- | -----------
Apples  |   5           | 8-25-2022 9:00:01 | Bearbear
Bananas |   10          | 8-25-2022 9:03:55 | Racc
Kiwis   |   3           | 8-25-2022 9:06:37 | Mickey
Oranges |   5           | 8-25-2022 9:07:24 | Bearbear
{: .datatable}
```

However, the table appears under the sidebar.
[image: sample page]

The way DataTables is implemented is through the following code in the `head.html` file:

```
<head>
    <!--The lines below help include JQuery DataTables into Markdown files-->
    {%- if page.datatable == true -%}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  <!--Add JQuery-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> <!--add style sheet-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> <!--add dataTables-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
        $('table.datatable').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
    {% endif %}
</head>
```

There is plenty of space for the datatable to be on the right of the sidebar. Does anyone know where the problem may be?

Comment: I found the following code in the `_base.scss` file:```/**
 * Tables
 */
table {
  margin-bottom: $spacing-unit;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: $table-text-align;
  color: lighten($text-color, 18%);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid $grey-color-light;
}``` Should the class option be added here? The way the table is displayed in the browser is `<table class="datatable dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info"></table>`

Comment: It happens to me when I remove float:left, which is weird anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float left is weird in this flexbox layout.

I have added flex to the page-content class in **sass/minima/_layout.scss**

```
.page-content {
    padding: 30px 0;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}
```

and a min-width (and max-width because I could not decide) to the sidebar CSS definition in **_sass/minima/_layout.scss** (or custom-styles.scss)

```
sidebar {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

I have uploaded my test page to GitHub:
https://github.com/cadamini/jekyll-minima-sidebar-test

Based on your comment, I have added some more changes to the CSS and HTML, also in the header, in this [commit](https://github.com/cadamini/jekyll-minima-sidebar-test/commit/ea18a9da105e2b0a686a0c85e518feaf75bea1f3). There are some comments in the commit to explain what I have done.

Comment: Thank you for the repo and for pointing out the specific places where code can be improved. Currently the table is on the right of the sidebar - yay! However, the Title has gotten to the right of the sidebar as well (still above the sidebar and the main content since it is part of the header). If the title can go back to the upper left corner that would be most fantastic!

Comment: Thanks for making the changes to the repo and sorry that your WSL striked! I have noticed that you made changes related to the header. I have made some tweaks to my blog backend based on yours, and I will make further tweaks if needed. If all else fails, I will attempt to replace my code with yours.

Comment: I forked your repo and tested it in my own browser, and the header works really nice, thanks! However, there seems to be a gap between the sidebar and the body of the blog. Do you have any idea why this is the case? Would it have something to do with the footer, or is it unrelated?

Comment: You'd need to share a screenshot. Of course, you can also try to use the browser dev tools and try to find out yourself.